# Traceback error when using urllib / BeautifulSoup. <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib, urlopen

I can run the below code fine on my MacBook at home, but when running the same code at work I get a traceback error. I think the issue may be a network issue but I'm not 100% sure so wanted to share the code and traceback here to see if a more experienced individual may be able to confirm or have a better idea of what is going wrong! (the same sort of error come up when I try to use the googlesearch-python library as well).

I am trying to run the following code:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Ann.com'

x=0
while x <7:
    x +=1

    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    tags = soup('a')
    url = tags[17].get('href', None)
    print('Retrieving:',url)
print(tags[17].contents[0])
```

And I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1354, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 950, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 921, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 787, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/u49063/Spittalj/env/Test Code/urllink_ex1.py", line 15, in <module>
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1383, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1357, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

I am running the code as a test to see if I can pull hyperlinks from a webpage and then go into those said hyperlinks.

The code failed with the above mentioned traceback - I think it may be a network / internet connection issues. (I am trying to run the code at work - when done at home on my personal laptop it works fine).

Comment: The host in the URL can not be resolved. Either a DNS or connection issue.